# How can I Use 2D Texture Paint in 3D View (Python)?

Tags: python, texture-painting

The 3D Fill tool fills the entire texture, while the 2D one respects different values within the image (only fills clicked sections). As a workaround I need to split the window and open Image Editor (2D) so I can properly fill with Fill tool. But I only want the 3D View open and have the same behavior in 3D View, without needing to open the Image Editor. Is this currently possible, perhaps with an override, or is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: can you please show screenshots and demonstrate how you do that manually? so I have an idea how to do it with python.

Comment: Is a video link okay here? https://youtu.be/CGLx7kIwCC8

I have the window split with 3D on the right, and 2D on the left, as you can see using the Paint Bucket on the right completely fills the entire mesh, while the 2D one on the left only fills the inside of the circle

Is there a good way to make use of the 2D version WITHOUT having the Image Editor window open?

Comment: Unfortunately the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.paint.html) doesn't tell us what exact command is executed when you do a fill. if i knew which command that was, i could come up with an operator to help you.

Comment: yeah no worries, looks like another "ill have to dig into the source" to see if there's anything, cheers!